# want to know , how to use Gridfs in to upload more than 16mb file/video using express,mongoose,mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

this my code, which works fine while uploading image but whenever I am going to upload video/files which is more than 16mb , its failed to upload , so what to do ,  please help , i am a beginner !
I am using formidable as a middleware , lodash and fs , But don't know to do next

```
const Freecoursevideo = require("../models/freecoursevideo");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const _ = require("lodash");
const fs = require("fs");


exports.createFreecoursevideo = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "problem with image",
      });
    }
    //destructure the fields
    const { name, description } = fields;

    if (!name || !description) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Please include all fields",
      });
    }

    let freecoursevideo = new Freecoursevideo(fields);
    console.log(freecoursevideo);
    //handle file here
    if (file.video) {
      if (file.video.size > 1000000000000000000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "File size too big!",
        });
      }
      freecoursevideo.video.data = fs.readFileSync(file.video.path);
      freecoursevideo.video.contentType = file.video.type;
    }

    // console.log(freecoursevideo);

    //save to the DB
    freecoursevideo.save((err, freecoursevideo) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: "Saving Freecoursevideo in DB failed",
        });
      }
      res.json(freecoursevideo);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: It would be good to see any error logs from when you try to upload an image over a certain size. It sounds more like a local configuration issue, than an actual code issue.

Comment: Which version of mongo you are using?

Comment: Max size of `1000000000000000000000` (which is 100 Exa Byte)? Imagine you would rip such a video to a stack of DVD's. It would create a stack from the Earth to the Moon. Better use a more realistic size like `10e9`, i.e. 10GB

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb has a limit of 16MB on the size of document which you can save to a collection.

Since you are trying to save videos of size greater than 16mb to your `freecoursevideo` collection, you are getting an error.

**Solution:-**

You will have to `Gridfs` to save documents of size greater than 16mb.

I your case i would suggest you get rid of `freecoursevideo` collection and save all your videos in `gridfs` whether it is more than 16mb or not. So that you don't have to query two places for getting your videos.

**So how to save to gridfs?**

- To start with just try to put some videos using mongoshell. Just navigate to the `bin` folder of your mongo database tools.

Ensure that the `bin` folder has following content.

[image]

- Open command prompt at this location. Run the below command by replacing , ,
  <DB_NAME> and <PATH_TO_VIDEO>

  `mongofiles --host=<HOST> --port=<PORT> -d=<DB_NAME> put <PATH_TO_VIDEO>`
- Above command will save the video in `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collections. Name of these collections are predefined by mongo and cannot be changed.
- Above exercise will you the understanding of how gridfs works. Then you can go ahead look for mongoose way of doing this. Adding a link to article that may help.

  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks...Can you accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: yes, it is useful , thanks alot , but still not understand how can i do this with node.js/express.js  ,,    if you know , please shear your knowledge sir,

Comment: Have you read this article I shared. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/